# Laser - damaging to your eyes?

Tags: laser

Will a <5mW laser Class IIIa become less dangerous to the eye if I supply it with less current/voltage? Or is there something about the laser itself that makes it dangerous?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that staring in to the sun would expose your eye to roughly 5mW of UV radiation, so I suppose it is somewhat as bad as that staring in to the laser for periods of time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general, the laser hazard depends on the laser power, the output beam diameter, and the laser wavelength. For a class IIIa or 3R laser (the "IIIa" designation is basically obsolete, although it remains in use for products certified before the new classes were defined), you're at low risk if you don't force yourself to stare into the beam. If the beam just happens to stray into your eye, you'll generally have a reflex response to look away from the painfully bright light. (Don't fight this reflex -- keep yourself safe). Note that the high end of the class 3R power limits is defined by the power where 50% of people will have an "aversion response" sufficient to avoid injury --- and the other 50% won't.

Reducing the current to a diode laser will reduce the output power, and thus make the output safer. However, most laser accidents don't happen when the laser is operated as intended or as planned. You also need to consider all the possible "fault conditions" or ways that things can go wrong.

Say you design a control circuit that regulates the laser output to always be less than 1 mW (in most cases, a "safe" level) using a feedback photodiode. For real safety, you should also consider things like

- What if the optical feedback path to the photodiode is blocked (by dirt getting in your box)?
- What if the electrical path from the feedback diode to its amplifier is broken?
- What if there is a spike or drift in the power supply to the laser or laser drive circuit?
- What if some bit of metal junk gets in your box and short-circuits the laser to the power supply, bypassing the power controller?
- How are you calibrating the limit value for the photodiode current? If you're setting it with a pot, could the pot drift or be mis-adjusted after calibration? If you're using a digital circuit, could the EEPROM with the cal data be erased or damaged?
- etc.

These are the kind of conditions that marketable laser products need to consider before they can pass regulatory requirements. Before you risk your eyesight with your laser system, you should at least consider doing this kind of analysis for yourself.

If you used a laser with less power capability, you would know that before any of these kind of hazards could lead to the laser producing a dangerous beam, the laser itself would burn itself up. If you use a laser capable of producing 5 mW before burning out, you'd be wise to treat it with a proportional level of respect.

Comment: Right answer for The Photon :)

Comment: Better answer than mine, +1.

Comment: One can implement one of a few crowbar circuits to save the laser diode when the output goes out of regulation, @Chief17 -- some are in [AoE](http://www.amazon.com/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521370957/).

Answer (score 4):

There are two main dangers from lasers:

The light is highly focused.

The light can be high intensity.

Because of these two factors, the energy density in the middle of the spot can be high enough to burn things, like your retina.  To reduce the energy density, reduce the combination of the two items above.  Running the laser with less current reduces #2, so yes, that makes it safer.

Comment: Thanks Olin, I don't suppose you have anything to add to Russell's answer below?

Comment: @Chief: After your first experiment, remember not to look into the laser with your remaining eye.

Comment: @OlinLathrop My lasers lab has the sign up, "Do not look at laser with remaining eye". However, I will say, if you hear a pop'ing sound when the laser hits you, that is a bad sign.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to explain and understand the basis for your question far more than you have done to make it able to be reasonably answered. As a rough guide, if you ask that sort of question at that degree of simplicity then you re dealing with something outside your safe competence level. That's not meant to be rude - just almost certainly true.

In most cases A LASER tends to work within a relatively restricted range of power outputs. You may be able to control one over a wide range if you know what you are doing but just changing the voltage is usually not going to work.

"Less dangerous" is hard to quantify.
 You are as liable to end up wholly blind but less blind than before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Russell, I am very new at electronics and this is my first 'project' so I do have a lot of questions. I have basically taken a laser from a laser pen and want to include it in my circuit to be powered along with the rest of the components, but Wikipedia says that Class IIIa can be mildly dangerous, so I tried decreasing the voltage and it dimmed the laser. I just wondered if this actually made it more safe to the eye? Could you elaborate on your answer and possibly explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Chief17 - What Russell is saying is that potentially dangerous stuff like lasers, high voltage, UV, or high-power motors are not good candidates for a first electronics project.  Consider looking into some low-power visible-light emitting diodes or small servos before tackling stuff that could potentially blind, electrocute, or maim you.

Comment: I know what your saying, and don't take this the wrong way, but its not really answering my question. I am cautious and everybody has to have a first try with lasers at some point. But thanks for the warning/advice anyway :)